# How to append text into html element with popup

Tags: jquery, html

I have  element in my webpage in which a button is placed. When I click on that button a popup window appears. In that popup window, there is a textarea and a submit button. I want that, whenever I click on popup submit button the entered text of textarea will get placed into the previous  and it s button will get remove.

Comment: Some code would be helpful, as well as some info on what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You've just got to fill up the html of the "previous" element with the text inside your textarea. the code snippet is pretty self explanatory

```
$("#yourFormId").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#idOfTheElementToFillUpWIthTheText").html($("#yourTextareaID").text());
    $("#yourButtonId").remove();
});
```